# Java Swing (BoxLayout) alignment issues

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, boxlayout

I am extremely new to Java Swing, and I'm having quite a bit of issues getting a nice layout going. I have checked out google, and even other answers on this website, but no information I find seems to solve the issue. Here is the result of my efforts:

[image]

As you can see, the label, text field, and button are all out of alignment. It is my goal for all of them to have the same left-hand border, and for the button and text field to have the same right-hand border, with these left and right hand borders being each the same distance from the left and righthand sides of my window.

Here are the important parts of my code:

```
    public void run()
    {
         JFrame frame = new JFrame("Arduino Server");
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         InstancePanel = new ServerGUIPanel();
         frame.getContentPane().add(InstancePanel);
         frame.pack();
         frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

And, in ServerGUIPanel.java:

```
    public ServerGUIPanel()
    {
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));



        StatusLabel = new JLabel("STATUS: BOOTUP");
        add(StatusLabel);

        PortField = new JTextField();
        PortField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(5000, 20));
        PortField.setMaximumSize(PortField.getPreferredSize());
        PortField.setActionCommand("PortChanged");
        add(PortField);

        ConnectionButton = new JButton();
        ConnectionButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(5000, 20));
        ConnectionButton.setMaximumSize(ConnectionButton.getPreferredSize());
        ConnectionButton.setActionCommand("ConnectionClicked");
        add(ConnectionButton);
    }
```

Does anyone have a simple solution to this? What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you very much!

--Georges Oates Larsen

Comment: @peeskillet Thank you for the suggestion! I did not end up using GridLayout, but I did use GridBagLayout, and that seems to be (so far) working.

Answer (score 2):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for the basics of using a BoxLayout as well as a section on alignment issues.

Basically you need to make sure the alignmentX value of all components is set to be left aligned.

Also:

1. Don't use setPreferredSize() to set the size of a component. Each Swing component will determine its own preferred size.
2. Use Java naming conventions. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: I have tried this; it appears they are left aligned by default. Having my elements all left aligned still results in each element fundamentally having different paddings/margins.

Comment: In response to #1: How do you recommend forcing my button to expand to the full width of the window, if not by using a large preferred size?

Comment: `I have tried this;` - You did something wrong. Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem. `How do you recommend forcing my button to expand to the full width of the window,` - you will need to use a different layout manager. A `GridLayout` will make all the components the same size. Or you can use a `GridBagLayout` and you can specify different "fill" values for each components. Again read the tutorial, you will also find sections on the above to layout managers with working examples.

Comment: @GeorgesOatesLarsen If you wan't the JButton to fill all availble space on it's row, then it is unlikely that you want to be using BoxLayout. Try GridBagLayout as recommended here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12174503/2081889

Comment: @Dæmon, camickr, I see! That makes sense. GridBagLayout seems to be working. Thank you for the link, Dæmon.

Comment: @camickr I am assuming that an SSCCE will not be needed at this stage, since I have switched to using GridBagLayout. Given that GridBagLayout is required for the type of layout alignment that I want (left-align still would not address the fact that I also want righthand borders to be aligned, as expressed in the post), I will accept your answer if you include GridBagLayout as an option.

Comment: @GeorgesOatesLarsen No problem. A good reference for the built-in Swing layouts can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), for the next time you are unsure of what LayoutManager to use.

Comment: @GeorgesOatesLarsen, `I will accept your answer if you include GridBagLayout as an option` - I already listed (and highlighted) as an option before Deamon even entered the conversation.

Comment: @Dæmon I see! You might consider consolidating your comments into an answer, since I would consider the information you provided worthy of being marked correct! (My problem all along was, at its core, using the wrong layout manager)

Comment: @camickr No amount of reading the tutorial for BoxLayout will fix the above problem, using BoxLayout will not cause both left, and right borders to be aligned. In my google search I have encountered most of the links that either of you have posted. Now if you want me to accept your answer, change your answer so that it focusses on the fact that I need a completely different layout manager, rather than simply dropping a link to a tutorial discussing my wrongly-chosen layout manager, without even going into any detail as to what my actual problem is, or why that manager was the wrong decision.

Comment: @GeorgesOatesLarsen, Based on a quick read of your question and from the picture I thought you were questioning why the components were not left aligned, so I just suggested the simple BoxLayout.  Then based on you second comment about forcing the button to the full width I suggested two possible layout managers you could use and even suggested which constraint you needed to use for the GridBagLayout. I assumed you could go from there, or if you needed more help you could reference the tutorial.

Comment: @camickr I'm not here to beat on your answer, nor question your reasoning. After all, you were the one to suggest using a GridBagLayout in the first place. But I'd rather not accept an answer based on the premise that the *real* answer is hidden in the comments. (Such a thing might confuse future programmers with the same problem). All I ask is that you change your answer (or perhaps even just post a second one) so that it focusses on GridBagLayout, since this is ultimately the required solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using setPreferredSize() AND setMaximumSize(). The latter will cause problems when stretching your main frame. [Your components will likely not want resize]

You should be using layout managers to handle all the alignments itself. I would stay away from using BoxLayout in this case, as different components want to size differently, and that will sway the alignment when added into your BoxLayout panel.

Moreover, you might want to give your main frame a layout as well.
Can you post how you used your GridBagLayout?